# Group records - keeping first Start Date (oldest) and last End Date (most recent)

Tags: powerquery

I'm new to Power Query, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem.

I have a dataset with ID, Status, Start Date and End Date. There are multiple rows for each ID with different start and end dates. Here's a sample of my dataset.

| ID | Status | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/04/2015 | 28/05/2015 |
| 1 | A | 28/05/2015 | 15/06/2016 |
| 1 | B | 15/06/2016 | 19/06/2016 |
| 1 | B | 19/06/2016 | 31/07/2016 |
| 1 | B | 31/07/2016 |  |
| 2 | B | 01/03/2017 | 03/06/2018 |
| 2 | A | 03/06/2018 | 07/08/2018 |
| 2 | A | 07/08/2018 | 31/12/2018 |
| 2 | C | 31/12/2018 | 01/09/2019 |
| 2 | C | 01/09/2019 | 03/05/2020 |
| 2 | A | 03/05/2020 |  |

I want to group consecutive rows (End Date same as the Start Date of next row) with same status for each ID and take the oldest Start Date and the most recent End Date. End Date will be blank for records that are still active. Here is the the output I'm looking for.

| ID | Status | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/04/2015 | 15/06/2016 |
| 1 | B | 15/06/2016 |  |
| 2 | B | 01/03/2017 | 03/06/2018 |
| 2 | A | 03/06/2018 | 31/12/2018 |
| 2 | C | 31/12/2018 | 03/05/2020 |
| 2 | A | 03/05/2020 |  |

Is this possible?

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Marc Pincince and  @Marius Durlea for your response. As @Storax' comments, I have got the solution now and it is [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Group-records-keeping-first-Start-Date-oldest-and-last-End-Date/m-p/1975119#M58206). Adding the code below too.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bZBLDoUgDEW3Yjom6YeHwFDfMoz734YtEKXRAYN7esItHAcwBNj0ECP9UIiTBilIqYczPM6EA3BCWi2st7N7rKF+O3VyohbntzPhAEsbyRjZqtFG2UIcd5Xb2TzWkJHKh/Pg1sfinb/HvbhaqM6ZcC+2PxJ67TNwe855AQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Status = _t, #"Start Date" = _t, #"End Date" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Status", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Status"}, {{"Start Date", each List.First([Start Date]), type nullable date}, {"End Date", each List.Last([End Date]), type nullable date}},GroupKind.Local

)
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 1):

This M code seems to work for what you described. It starts with your sample data in a table named Table1 in an Excel spreadsheet.

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "New Start Date", 
    each if [Index] = 0 or ([Index] > 0 and [ID] = #"Added Index"[ID]{[Index]-1} and [Status] <> #"Added Index"[Status]{[Index]-1}) then [Start Date] 
    else if [ID] <> #"Added Index"[ID]{[Index]-1} 
        then [Start Date] 
    else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "New Finish Date", 
    each if [Index] = List.Last(#"Added Index"[Index]) or ([ID] <> #"Added Index"[ID]{[Index]+1} or [Status] <> #"Added Index"[Status]{[Index]+1}) then [End Date] 
    else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"New Start Date"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Date Flag", 
    each if [Index] = 0 
        then if ([ID] <> #"Filled Down"[ID]{[Index]+1} or [Status] <> #"Filled Down"[Status]{[Index]+1}) or ([ID] = #"Filled Down"[ID]{[Index]+1} and [Status] = #"Filled Down"[Status]{[Index]+1} and [New Start Date] <> #"Filled Down"[New Start Date]{[Index]+1}) 
            then 1 
        else 0 
    else if [Index] = List.Last(#"Filled Down"[Index]) 
        then 1 
    else if ([ID] = #"Filled Down"[ID]{[Index]-1} and [Status] = #"Filled Down"[Status]{[Index]-1} and [New Start Date] <> #"Filled Down"[New Start Date]{[Index]+1}) or ([ID] = #"Filled Down"[ID]{[Index]+1} and [Status] <> #"Filled Down"[Status]{[Index]+1} and [New Start Date] <> #"Filled Down"[New Start Date]{[Index]+1}) 
        then 1 
    else 0),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2", each ([Date Flag] = 1)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID", "Status", "New Start Date", "New Finish Date"})
in
#"Removed Other Columns"
```

Comment: Do not worry. This guy has already gotten an answer [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Group-records-keeping-first-Start-Date-oldest-and-last-End-Date/m-p/1975119#M58206)

Comment: Thanks @Storax. The answer at the link is actually much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

First. You must change null value in End Data with Today Data
Second. Group by advanced... ID and Status  with 2 New column name: min for Start data and max for End data
Below you have the code:

P.S. #Promoted Headers is necessary only in my sample.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Status", type text}, {"Start Date", type datetime}, {"End Date", type datetime}}),
    #"Replaced null withToday" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1",null,DateTime.LocalNow(),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"End Date"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced null withToday", {"ID", "Status"}, {{"Minim Data (1)", each List.Min([Start Date]), type nullable datetime}, {"Maxim Data (1)", each List.Max([End Date]), type nullable datetime}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```